# What do you use to "package"?

Tags: word-request

Imagine this situation. 
You have a machine that is going to do some **packaging**
The output of this processes are **packages**
How do you call the "raw material" that you use for packaging?

---

Now, I can see that this can be very ample, for example if there are already plastic packages ready to be filled and sealed, I would call those "packages" too, but what if the raw materials before packaging are not already formed packages but a large piece of plastic (that somehow the machine folds and seals forming a fully formed "package")

In the original documents (in other language) they are called "packaging paper" but I am not sure what a native english speaker would call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the materials used to package things, are also collectively called *packaging*.

> [**packaging**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/packaging): *the materials in which objects are wrapped before being (shipped or) sold*

You can be more precise and talk specifically about different components involved in the packaging process:

> *boxing, packing, wrapping, crating, taping, strapping, sealing, labeling, etc.*

which use, respectively,

> *boxes, packing (material), wrapping (material), crates, tape, straps (or strapping), sealant, labels*, etc.

Unless the packaging is actually made of paper I would not call it "packaging paper".  If it is soft and transparent I would call it "plastic wrap", but it sounds more like a custom, form-fitted, plastic *container*.

This can have many different names, but the most common terms are *shrink wrap*, *blister pack*, and *clamshell pack*.

Comment: Thanks. Depending on the settings sometimes it is paper and sometime transparent plastic, (the procedure is the same) so how about "package wrap"?

Comment: @KansaiRobot the generic "wrap" or "wrapping" covers paper and plastic.